# BizTalk: SB Messaging Adapter: Does it poll ? or any other call back?

Tags: biztalk, azure-servicebus-queues

I have a Receive Location in BizTalk. (based on SB-Messaging Adapter). It receives messages from Azure SB Queue.
How does it work ? Does it poll ? What is the polling interval ? 
Or does it receive via any other callback ?

Thanks
Prabath

Answer (score 0):

Don't quote me...this may just be a poor recollection of a event session...

I think both, meaning, the adapter opens a connection to the queue, waits a certain amount of time to receive a message, or several messages, then closes the connection only to reopen immediately.

Why do you ask?  There may be a more appropriate answer depending on your circumstances.